# Using wsgen to generate all necessary Java artifacts - class not found

Tags: java, web-services, wsgen

I have the following class

```
HelloWorld.java      - interface
HelloWorldImpl.java  - service implementation
HelloWorldPublisher  - publisher
```

in the directory,

```
C:\Users\ANSARI\Desktop\Lexicon\WorkSpaceLuna\WebServices\DocumentStyle\src\com\
farhan\ws
```

I tried to use the wsgen command from the command prompt in the manner shown below,

[image]

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are in the `src` directory (as indicated by the path `\src\com\farhan\ws`) and therefore the class file cannot be found (wsgen operates on the byte code, not on Java sources).

Change into the eclipse project directory

```
 cd \Users\ANSARI\Desktop\Lexicon\WorkSpaceLuna\WebServices\DocumentStyle
```

and execute the following command:

```
 wsgen -cp bin -keep -s src -d bin com.farhan.ws.HelloWorldImpl
```

The option `-cp` defines the classpath (the path where the class file for `HelloWorldImpl` can be found). The `-s` option specifies where to place the generated source files and `-d` specifies where to place the generated output files.

Note: I think that it is not necessary to generate artefacts using `wsgen` with the JAX-WS implementation which is part of the JDK. The necessary classes are generated on the fly. It should be possible to start your publisher without invoking `wsgen` (but I have not found a confirmation of this statement in the docs).